# Library based application installs 2 APK files, not one - Why?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-library, library-project, apk

I am trying to restructure an existing app so that, except for a few override-able methods in a derived activity, all code will reside in a library. This still [doesn't work for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325826/unable-to-instantiate-activity-caused-by-classnotfoundexception), but in the process of attempting to troubleshoot this, I discovered much to my dismay that there are **two** .apk files installed, not one (when I run a debug session from eclipse):

1. The first (and larger file) is
   having the original library name.
2. The second (only 20KB in size) is
   having the derived application name.

Why is that and where can I learn more about this?

Could that explain the [ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325826/unable-to-instantiate-activity-caused-by-classnotfoundexception) problem I am having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer myself. It turns out that I had 2 critical settings in the Properties of both projects not set correctly:

1. In the library project, "Is Library"
   was not checked for some reason. I
   could swear that I checked it, but
   knowing how whimsical the Android
   development environment under
   Eclipse can be, I suspect that it
   was unchecked by Eclipse (or the ADT
   plugin) as a result of some glitch.
2. In the application project, I
   neglected to add my library project
   as a reference via the Add...
   button. (how dumb could I be?)

Hoping this can be useful for other newbies to come.

Comment: I had the same problem and had done what you indicated already. For me it turns out the problem was that I had the library in the build path in addition to being added as a library already. Once I removed it from the build path, it was all good!