# Application using LVL installs TWO icons

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-lvl, library-project

The dual-icon saga continues... It turns out that while [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332871/library-based-application-installs-2-apk-files-not-one-why/6333690#6333690) may be true for the debug version (yes, I still manage to display only one icon when installing the APK via Eclipse when debugging), it doesn't seem to work for the exported version.

The interesting thing is that the export function generates (successfully) only one APK, but when installed to the device, **two** icons show up on the launcher, not one.

So far, the only thing special I have been able to identify about this weird problem is that it uses a Library project. Two Library projects, to be more exact: One is Google's LVL, the other is my own Library project. I may be mistaken but I don't have any other clue as to why this is happening: I verified that for **both** libraries the `Is Library` checkbox is checked and that the application project references both of them in the `Properties > Android > Library` section.

How do I begin to troubleshoot something like this?

**UPDATE:** After delving a little deeper (inspecting the file system using `adb shell`) I discovered that the directory `/data/data/com.android.vending/cache/` contains two files for the aforementioned application:

```
-rw-------    1 app_44   app_44         415 Jun 21 09:10 AVMC_UAR{com.example.myapp.lvl_}_____0_10_rei____
-rw-------    1 app_44   app_44          74 Jun 21 09:10 AVMC_UCRcom.example.myapp.lvl_0_10_self_
```

The culprit, then, seems to be Google's LVL... but why is this happening and why am I the only one reporting about this?

**UPDATE 2:** The files prefixed with `AVMC_UAR` are automatically generated when accessing the Android Market either "from within" or "for" the application. So, this *may be* a **symptom** of the problem, not the cause.

The quest for solving this mystery continues...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you including in `AndroidManifest.xml` by any chance an activity from your library with the a MAIN and LAUNCHER intent filter?

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was the problem indeed.

Comment: Clarification: My application's `AndroidManifest.xml` included the library's main activity (in addition to its own activity). The library's main activity should be included in the library's manifest only. The application's manifest should have **only one** main activity (i.e. with MAIN and LAUNCHER).