# What does checking the "is Library" checkbox do "Under the Cover"?

Tags: android, android-library, library-project

I noticed that when I convert an existing Android Application project to an Android Library project [by checking the "is Library" checkbox](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject), nothing changes in the project's source code or XML files.

So what really happens when the "is Library" checkbox is checked? What changes internally, **in the package and/or project files**? Where can I learn more about this?

To better explain my question:

1. What I am interested to know (mainly
   for troubleshooting purposes) is
   **what differentiates** an Application package from a Library
   package "under the cover"?
2. Is the fact that a project is
   "Library Project" **marked
   somewhere**? If so, where does it
   mark it (obviously not in the source
   files and not even in the res XML
   files)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Managing Projects from the Command Line page](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html#SettingUpLibraryProject):

> The create lib-project command creates
>   a standard project structure that
>   includes preset property that
>   indicates to the build system that the
>   project is a library. It does this by
>   adding this line to the project's
>   default.properties file:
>
> `android.library=true`

In other words, it's a property that is utilized by the build system and not by the operating system.

UPDATE: I'm on my iPhone so I won't type out a whole paraphrase, but here's a pretty good blog article discussing the differences between a Java JAR and an Android Library Project, including how the dex tools add the resources and dex code to the .apk:

http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/android-application-android-libraries-and-jar-libraries/

Comment: @Doug Stephen +1 already for answering question #2. Do you also happen to know what differentiates an Application package from a Library package "under the cover"?

Comment: @an00b No problem.  Don't forget to award the bounty though... I wants me some rep :)

Comment: @Doug Stephen I thought the bounty is automatically awarded to the accepted answer. Apparently this isn't the case. I just tried to click the +50 icon to award the bounty, but SO says I can only do it in 20 hours.

Comment: Heh no worries. I ran up on the sane thing first time I awarded a bounty. I thought it was automatic too.

Answer (score 5):

From the devsite: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

> You can also designate an Android
>   project as a library project, which
>   allows it to be shared with other
>   projects that depend on it. Once an
>   Android project is designated as a
>   library project, it cannot be
>   installed onto a device.

Comment: That's from the link that I posted in my question, but it doesn't explain what happens **internally**. Sorry for not explaining my question well. What I am interested to know (mainly [for troubleshooting purposes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325826/unable-to-instantiate-activity-caused-by-classnotfoundexception)) is what differentiates an Application package from a Library package "under the cover".

Answer (score 1):

A library project isn't packaged as a seperate redistributable file as you're used to with a jar. It's merged with the the apk file of your application.

The page you linked to mentions it in the [Referencing a library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) section.

> As soon as the Properties dialog closes, Eclipse rebuilds the project, including the contents of the library project.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for highlighting this. What I am trying to understand is whether the fact that a project is "Library Project" is **marked somewhere**? If so, where does it mark it (obviously not in the source files and not even in the res XML files)?