# Android ComponentInfo ClassNotFoundException on some devices

Tags: android

Please help to understand strange application behaviour.
In almost all devices in production everything is OK, I'm using ACRA to collect crash reports. But here is what I've got from Alpha GTR device:

```
ComponentInfo{com.xxxxxxxxxxx /com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxActivity
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2108)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxActivity
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
... 11 more   
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxActivity
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So application failed to start with strange exception. I've already checked SO questions about it, and just adding libraries as [Unable to instantiate activity... Caused by ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325826/unable-to-instantiate-activity-caused-by-classnotfoundexception) doesn't help here.
Could it be some device-specific exception? My app uses Camera, Google Maps and GPS.

Comment: Do you added all the permissions correctly and have added the maps library in manifest. ? Have created the project with google API target ?

Comment: Are you using Proguard? Is the activity declared correctly in your manifest file?

Comment: @etienne I don't use Proguard, and all other devices being checked works fine

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys yep, google API target and maps library are OK

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to check if GPS or Camera are supported by the device first?

```
LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: Crashed-on device http://android-devices.net/devices/hardware/highscreen-alpha-gtr/ should support this features, but interesting question is about have user allowed to apps use them. But in this case other exception should be thrown?